# Throwing an error when trying to send a embed

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, embed

I'm trying to create an embed using **discord.js v12** and it keeps showing this error

> DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message

Heres my code:

```
        const infoembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(responce.asset.title)
            
        umsg.channel.send({ embeds: infoembed });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `responce.asset.title` is empty - you will get an error because discord can't send embed with empty title! But you can try using this code:

```js
const infoembed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#0099ff')
      .setTitle(`** **`);

umsg.channel.send(infoembed)
```

Comment: The funny thing it actually works

Comment: `message.channel.send(infoembed)` is not the correct way to send embeds

Comment: It's not the best way, but I can see no reason to downvote it if it **works**, while your code still give them an error

Comment: That's not the way how to code :D It shouldn't be "It's okay as long as it works somehow". Especially if you're new to programming it's important to understand the code and do it the right way

Comment: Maybe this solution works for you, but if you've ever taken a look at the docs and how to create & send embeds, you'll notice that this is not correct. Btw on which version of discord.js are you?

Comment: Discord.js v12.5.3

Comment: For discord.js v12+ `message.channel.send(infoembed)` would work, but this version is outdated and not everyone is using it anymore

Comment: But how you can be sure they are 100% using djs v13?

Comment: He tried it using `umsg.channel.send({ embeds: infoembed });`, thats why I assumed he's using v13

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft it might work in 1 scenario but not another. An example is multiplying by 2. If you have the number 2, you can add 2. You get the correct result, but the wrong way to *get it*. It's not necessarily the *right* way, but it will obviously not work with any other number, for example 6. 6*2 = 12 but 6+2 = 8.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you're on **discord.js v13** you have to put your embed in an **array**:</s>

```js
const infoembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(responce.asset.title)
            
umsg.channel.send({ embeds: [infoembed] });
```

And if you want to add some **text content** to the message you simply have to add the field `content`:

```js
const infoembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(responce.asset.title)
            
umsg.channel.send({ content: 'Hello world!', embeds: [infoembed] });
```

---

Since you're using discord.js v12, you have to remove the **curly brackets** and the `embeds` field:

```js
const infoembed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#0099ff')
            .setTitle(responce.asset.title)
            
umsg.channel.send(infoembed);
```

Comment: umsg.channel.send({ embeds: [infoembed] }); still returns the same error

Comment: Is `responce` your actual variable or a typo?

Comment: it is my actual var, I'm dyslexic sorry

Comment: And have to already debugged `responce.asset.title` to check if it's `null` or **empty**?

Comment: Try replacing `.setTitle(responce.asset.title)` with `.setTitle("Test")`

Comment: i have and its not null or empty and I've tried .setTitle("Test") it still returns the error!

Comment: Have you tried it **with** the `content` field? In my case, when I don't specify the `content` I get the same error

Comment: it just sends "Hello world" and no embed

Comment: Try creating the embed as an object: `const embed = { color: 0x0099ff, title: 'Test' }` and send it like this: `umsg.channel.send({ content: 'Hello world!', embeds: [infoembed] });`

Comment: Seems like you were using discord.js v12. Since v13 is the latest version, you should add this information to your question ;)

Answer (score 0):

All messages sent by bots now support up to 10 embeds. As a result, the `embed` option was removed and replaced with an `embeds` array, which must be in the `options` object.

```js
umsg.channel.send({ embeds: [infoembed] });
```

[Read documentation](https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v13.html#sending-messages-embeds-files-etc)

Comment: umsg.channel.send({ embeds: [infoembed] }); still returns the same error